# Johnson's or Johnsons

Tags: apostrophe

I am ordering a flag.  It says "Welcome Summer" and then under that is the name 
                               The Johnsons or The Johnson's

Husband and wife live in one dwelling.  I know if it stated The Johnson's Home that would be proper, but it just doesn't look right..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the phrase is intended as a signature, then the possessive does not apply; it's a simple plural - the members of the Johnson family are simply "The Johnsons".

If, on the other hand, you are referring to their house, you have (at least) two choices:

- Possessive: the Johnsons' house (the house belonging to the Johnsons)
- Adjectival:

  - the Johnson house (this would be more common if the house were a local landmark, e.g. "Turn right at the old Johnson house")
  - Johnson House (in the case of e.g. a charitable foundation)

In the case of a name ending in -s (Jones, for example), form the plural and the plural possessive in the usual way: "Keeping up with the Joneses"; "I'm heading over to the Joneses' house."

Comment: There is also a common alternative to this: *The Johnson family's house.*

Answer (score -2):

If the proper name is *Johnson*, **Mark Johnson**, then it would **The Johnson's**, as in, **the house that belongs to the Johnson family.**

If the proper name is *Johnsons*, e.g., **Barry Johnsons**, then it would **The Johnsons'**, as in, **the house that belongs to the Johnsons family.**

Referring to a married couple, you could use plural, e.g, "The Johnsons (surname: Johnson) throw great parties." But it seems awkward or dangerous to then mark plural with possessive, when you are referring to a singular proper noun. Back to your example, it isn't the case the the husband OWNS the house *and* the wife OWNS the house -- rather that *they* own the house *together*.

Comment: "The Johnson's" doesn't seem possible to me--I can't use a possessive this way. I can only hear this as *The Johnsons* or *The Johnsons'*--to me, it feels like it has to be plural. Can you cite a source to support this answer?

Comment: If Mark Johnson lived there by himself, then "The Johnson's" would be correct, but very curiously written with the definite article. But if Mark has a wife and children, and the house was possessed by all then surely it has to be "The Johnsons' house".  In the case of Barry Johnsons, I would write it in exactly the same way, but there are people who would argue that it should be "The Johnsonses' house".

Comment: When I worked at the UK TV Licensing office, I once opened a letter which ended I AM MR'S JONE'S. I'd use 'The Johnsons'.

Comment: Never u'se an apo'strophe to s'ay your word's are plural's.

Comment: They are known as "grocers' apostrophes", from the formers' tendency to put up signs that contain superfluous apostrophes. I know of one instance of a grocer's apostrophe on a gravestone.